# Parameterizing the browser in Serenity BDD

Tags: java, serenity-bdd

I have multiple scenarios in my feature file and I want to execute each scenario in a specific browser.

Can we instantiate the browser by passing the browser value in the feature file?

For example,

```
@TC1
Scenario Outline: Login
Given the user instantiates the browser "<browser>"
When the user navigates to the URL "<url>"
And enters the username as "<username>" and the password as "<password>" 
And clicks the login button
Then the user will be redirected to the home page
Examples:
|browser|url|username|password|
|chrome|https://mail.google.com|JohnSmith|Pass123|
```

Alternatively, in the method **newDriver()** is it possible to retrieve the scenario name or the tag name during runtime before instantiating the browser (the method getName() of the Scenario class returns null), so that I can refer an external file and instantiate the browser that has been mapped to the scenario or the tag?

If neither of the above two methods is possible, is there any other way to parameterize the browser for each Scenario in the feature file?